# Create Dot Net Nuke user from code

Tags: c#, cryptography, dotnetnuke-5

Can someone please tell me if it possible to create a new user in a dotnetnuke application from code? I have a list of users that I wish to be added via a windows service.

I've figured out how to write the t-sql side of things but I need to pass in the encrypted password into the procedure, I think I know how to do this as I have access to the machine key, but in the database there is an extra field called passwordsalt, how do I generate this?

Answer (score 3):

`UserController` class has static methods:

```
CreateUser(ByRef objUser As UserInfo) As UserCreateStatus

GeneratePassword() As String

ChangePassword(ByVal user As UserInfo, 
               ByVal oldPassword As String, 
               ByVal newPassword As String) As Boolean
```

Before calling `CreateUser`, you'll need to create a `UserInfo` object and set the properties required for a user, such as the `Username`. UserController passes the UserInfo to the membership provider, which validates and creates the user. See `UserController` and `AspNetMembershipProvider` in the DNN source for more details.

Comment: ok so I'm now trying to use DNN usercontroller class but I keep getting the following error "The type initializer for 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Profile.ProfileController' threw an exception"

Comment: Update your original question with what exception you are getting. I am going to guess your code is simply wrong.  I am going to guess your UserInfo object is null.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please tell me if it possible to create a new user in a
>   dotnetnuke application from code?

If it wasn't possible then dotnetnuke itself couldn't create a user.  Look at the code for DotNetNuke and see how a user is created.

> I've figured out how to write the t-sql side of things but I need to
>   pass in the encrypted password into the procedure, I think I know how
>   to do this as I have access to the machine key, but in the database
>   there is an extra field called passwordsalt, how do I generate this?

Do yourself a favor and do NOT run your own t-sql query use the method that creates a user instead.